# Problema de lógica JAVA Programa relógio

Tags: java

Boa tarde meus caros estou com uma dificuldade com a lógica desse programa que é um relógio:

```
private void updateDisplay() {

        if(hours.getValue()==0 && (periodo=="am" || periodo =="AM")){
              hours.setValue(hours.getValue()+1);
              periodo = "am";
        }
        else{
            if(hours.getValue()==12 && (periodo=="am" || periodo =="AM")){
                periodo="pm";
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        if(hours.getValue()==0 && (periodo=="pm" || periodo =="PM")){
                hours.setValue(hours.getValue()+1);
                periodo="pm";
        }
        else{

        }


         displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
                    minutes.getDisplayValue() + " " + periodo; 
    }
}
```

Todas as funções estão perfeitas realmente é só a parte da lógica que ta complicado. E quero limitar entre 1-12 por isso quando chega no limite que é 11:59 pm ele vira 12:00 am e quando chega 11:59 am vira 12:00 pm.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto:

```
if(hours.getValue()==0 && (periodo.equals("am") || periodo.equals("AM")){

        hours.setValue(hours.getValue()+1);
        periodo = "am";

    }else if(hours.getValue()==12 && (periodo.equals("pm") || periodo.equals("PM")){

        hours.setValue(hours.getValue()+1);
        periodo = "pm";

    }else if(hours.getValue()==0 && (periodo.equals("pm") || periodo.equals("PM")){

        hours.setValue(hours.getValue()+1);
        periodo="pm";

    }else if (hours.getValue()==12 && (periodo.equals("am") || periodo.equals("AM")){

        hours.setValue(hours.getValue()+1);
        periodo="am";

    }
```

espero que isto ajude!

Comment: exemplo quando chega a 11:58 am e eu chamo o método de pular minuto vai para 11:59 am e repetindo mais uma vez vai para 12:00 am sendo q deveria ser pm pois esses dois iff tão conflitando eu acho ai prevalece o am q é o ultimo qnd estiver no período das 12 horas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ter uma outra função que vai servir como flag:
Toda vez que ele atingir o valor de 12:00, ele vai chamar essa função:
Se o valor anterior dela for AM, essa função vai retonar PM.
Se o valor anterior dela for PM, essa função vai retonar AM.

alguma coisa como

```
if (hours.getDisplayValue()==12 && minutes.getDisplayValue()==00){
    stringAmPm=verificaAmPm(stringAmPm)
        if (stringAmPm = "AM"){
            escreve que está de dia}
        else  {
            escreve que está de noite
        }
    }


private verificaAmPm (stringAmPm)
    if (stringAmPm = "AM") {
        stringAmPm = "PM"
    }
    else {
        stringAmPm = "AM"
    }
    return stringAmPm
```

Comment: vou tentar implementar

Comment: ae consegui @Roni Antonio fazendo do teu jeito :D vlw mesmo